# How long to wait for formal offer letter?

Tags: job-offer, email

I finished my 2 rounds of interview with a company 'A' on Friday evening. First one was telephonic and second was on-site. After on-site interview, I had sent out a 'thank you' email to the HR. After 15 minutes, he confirmed me via reply email that technical team was pleased with my skill set and wants me to be on board. He also mentioned key things about salary, contract period (X months) and position. He mentioned that formal letter would be issued on Monday shortly thereafter. I asked for few more dollars besides the salary offered. Monday has passed by and I still didn't receive any reply from the company HR and today is Tuesday.

Do I need to worry anything about the offer? Did I do any mistake of asking few more dollars than what I offered.

Comment: I'm not sure where you live, but "formal letter" probably means snail mail. Do you really expect them to send this letter by magic-teleporting-express? A real life letter can easily take two to three days.

Comment: "Formal letter" would mean a PDF copy of the offer letter with all the position details, salary and date of joining.

Comment: On Friday itself, I received a confirmation email about the hiring decision. I am waiting for the offer letter and this wait is killing me :-(

Comment: How and when did you bring up a bigger salary?

Comment: Not adding this as an answer, as it's essentially the same... but wait it out. Give them a shout-out via email if you must, but the bigger the company the longer it simply takes, and the manager is not HR and may not understand all of the hoops that are required. I lost out on a dream job because I didn't trust them when they said "it's coming" and out of work. It's a big regret of my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to worry anything about the offer? Did I do any mistake of
>   asking few more dollars than what I offered.

Your interview was Friday, and you were told you would get an offer on Monday. Even though they promised Monday, it's reasonable to wait a week to hear from them.

It sounds as if your counter-offer was the last event in the chain. If so, it's possible that the hiring manager needs more time to respond, since you changed the details at that point.

Asking for a few more dollars wasn't necessarily a mistake, unless the manager believed that all the details were already settled, and just the formality of a signed offer letter remained. At some point, negotiations need to end - it's possible that you didn't think you reached that point, where the hiring manager did. That's probably not what happened, but only you and the hiring manager can know that. Either way, it's probably not a big mistake, and likely isn't worth worrying about at this point.

If it were me, I'd wait until the end of the week. If I still hadn't heard, then I'd call the hiring manager, remind him that I hadn't yet received the formal offer letter that was promised. I'd ask if there was any other information he needed from me.

Answer (score 0):

If they said you'd receive something by Monday and it's passed Monday then its ok to go ahead and give them a call or shoot them an e-mail about the offer letter. Whenever someone gives you their word you can always ask them about it when that time has passed, just shoot them a professional e-mail asking if they've sent out the formal letter yet and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

It can take weeks for a company to finish processing all applicants, make its decisions, and send out official letters. Negotiating salary re-opens that evaluation, since they now háve to decide again if you're that much better than the second-choice candidate. If you're going to try to do this, you have to accept that the additional delay is by your own choice .